# Do not allow to create 2nd reference (unique_ptr behaviour in C#)

Tags: c#

How to prevent the user of an API to store references to objects returned by the API, e.g. hold reference outside of using block or store outside of a callback (Action delegate call) when provided as argument?

Answer (score 2):

You can't keep people from keeping references around. What you can do is make the object useless. Implementing [`IDisposable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) seems like a good way to do this. So you can make your callback call like this to ensure that it's disposed once the callback is done:

```
using (var myDisposable = GetStuff())
    myAction(myDisposable);
```

It's up to you to document your API and then trust your users to not shoot themselves in the foot with it.

Comment: Explicit calls to `GC.Collect()` in debug mode and counting survivors can also help detect references being kept outside the appropriate scope.

Comment: If your API consists of only a few classes, you could create type-specific wrappers around all of them, with each wrapper holding a `WeakReference<T>` of the *real* object in a private field. (`IDisposable` is a much nicer approach. Just tossing out ideas here for sake of discussion!)